# SSL Pinning on iOS for Ionic Angular Application

Tags: ios, xcode, ssl, ionic-framework, sslpinning

I have a problem with SSL Pinning on iOS. I was using the following plugin:

https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http

and

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http

This method is working fine for Android. However, with iOS, I am receiving the following error on Xcode:

```
Connection 1: default TLS Trust evaluation failed(-9813)
Connection 1: TLS Trust encountered error 3:-9813
Connection 1: encountered error(3:-9813)
```

I am not sure how to fix this problem. I've googled everywhere, and most of the solution is for Android, and not iOS specifically.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you find any solution? I have the same problem too.

Comment: @ChrisJoo took me 2 months, but I found the problem is with the certificate. You can read how I solved it here, wrote this as a reminder to myself too-> https://javascript.plainenglish.io/ionic-5-and-above-ssl-pinning-for-ios-b77f17d9e6a6

Comment: Thank you... I found a solution luckily... The problem came from my wrong certificate file serving from cert.pem not fullchain.pem file... Also I changed app.componet.ts code ( i.e., iOS: this.httpSSL.setServerTrustMode('default');  , Android: this.httpSSL.setServerTrustMode('pinned');